# Access denied when making ajax request in onpaste event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

In my asp.net mvc website I am making an ajax call to my server when the user pastes something in a certain textbox. This call used to work in IE 8, but now it stopped working in IE 11, giving me an access denied exception in my jQuery 1.7.1 at `h.open(c.type,c.url,c.async)`.

Long research hinted me that it might be related to a CORS issue, but... every call is on the same domain.

```
<input type="text" id="Pasteexcelhere" name="Pasteexcelhere" />


   <script type='text/javascript' >
     $(function () {
         onp();
     });
     function onp() {
         obj = document.getElementById('Pasteexcelhere');    

         $('#Pasteexcelhere').on('paste', function (e) {              
             x = obj.value;
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "<%= Url.Action("PasteFromExcel", "RequestData" ) %>",
                 data: "{'data': '" + x + "'}",                   
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 traditional: true,                     
                 success: function (da) {
                     alert("success");
                 },
                 error: function (d) {
                     alert(d.statusText); // access denied
                 }
             });
         });
 </script>
```

When trying to make the same call directly, let's say via a simple link:

```
<a id="mylink" href="#" onclick="blubb();return false;">Pasted</a>

<script type='text/javascript' >
function blubb() {           
         obj = document.getElementById('Pasteexcelhere');
         x = obj.value;
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "<%= Url.Action("PasteFromExcel", "RequestData" ) %>",
                 data: "{'data': '" + x + "'}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 traditional: true,                     
                 success: function (da) {
                     var propertyGrid = $('#RequestedTickers').data('tGrid');
                     propertyGrid.rebind({});

                 },
                 error: function (d) {
                     alert(d.statusText);
                 }

             });

         };
</script>
```

It works just as expected... (no access denied)

Does anybody have an idea how to get this to run?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe it's not working because the obj doesn't exists when you call onp()

Comment: If i put a breakpoint there, the "obj" looks absolutely fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it doesn't work only when pasting, the problem seems to be with the paste event-handler.

After searching for problems with IE11 and the paste-event I found among others "[IE11 pasting clipboard data to an input element annoyance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640392/ie11-pasting-clipboard-data-to-an-input-element-annoyance)" on StackOverflow.

It might be a long shot, but a you could try the same "solution" (=workaround) that AlvinfromDiaspar provided as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19648893/102693) in that post:

```
$('#Pasteexcelhere').on('paste', function () { setTimeout(blubb, 100) });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The code was triggering jQuery AJAX request inside *paste* event listener. This caused the xhr.open(...) to throw an **Invalid Argument** exception from the jQuery code shown below. The exception occurred only when running the code in **IE11**:

```
jQuery.ajaxTransport( function( options ) {
var callback, errorCallback;

// Cross domain only allowed if supported through XMLHttpRequest
if ( support.cors || xhrSupported && !options.crossDomain ) {
    return {
        send: function( headers, complete ) {
            var i,
                xhr = options.xhr();

            xhr.open(
                options.type,
                options.url,
                options.async,
                options.username,
                options.password
            );
```

The change suggested by @lx fixed this. The code was changed from:

```
$('#my_input').on('paste', onPaste);

function onPaste(e)
{
    triggerAjaxCall(...)
}
```

to

```
$('#my_input').on('paste', onPaste);

function onPaste(e)
{
    setInterval(function () { triggerAjaxCall(...) }, 100);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@lx thanks for this, your solution works however my solution doesn't use JQuery so I had to look further into it. I wasn't getting the access denied as @trykyn was however I was getting an issue of the textbox being blank after pasting ~(only a right click and paste) when fired direct from a `<textarea onpaste="ThisIsMyPasteFunction()"></textarea>`

I found that in my case I had to use `onpaste="setTimeout(function () { ThisIsMyPasteFunction() }, 1)` as even although `ThisIsMyPasteFunction` had a `setTimeout(function () { anotherfunction() } , 1)` inside it, it would always return as a blank textarea value until I set the `setTimeout` directly on the `onpaste`.

Hope that this helps others if they're not using JQuery in their code :-)

Very weird how right click and paste doesn't work but ctrl+v does

Regards
Liam